# How to resolve " java.sql.sqlexception access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' " in spring boot even user having all privileges?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, mariadb

Access denied for user in spring boot even user having all privileges.
Error Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]

        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]

        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
```

Comment: it is probably what it says. check password twice. check if you are able to login with the password from console. check user privileges. if still not solved then share the details.

Comment: Hey Thanks for concerning About this, I actually resolved and posted the answer here as how I gone through.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue when I am running spring boot application on Cent OS7 server. When I got that error as usually I put it on google,stackoverflow and so on to fix this.

And I have followed all the answers like "Granting User privileges in DB, enabling 3306 over tcp/ip, drop user & try to create new user blah blah. Phew But I already did all these things still error throwing.

At last I found how to fix. Its dead simple if you see the steps below

Locate your DB server. (linux) Execute the command below

> > netstat -apn | grep 3306

check the status from the Output as port 3306 should be ESTABLISHED like below

*tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:60932   127.0.0.1:3306    ESTABLISHED  **7289/java***

If it seems like TIME_WAIT which I was getting earlier, please kill the java process by its Process ID
So here Process id I : 7289

> > kill -9 processid

Restart your spring boot application

THATS ALL ERROR GONE WHEN I RESTARTS THE APP